# ForkJoinPool. Really parallel. How?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, forkjoinpool

I'm new to `ForkJoinPool` framework. Don't quite get it, how is that achieved that each thread in `ForkJoinPool` is certainly run by separate processor/core to provide real parallelism considering that there are many other threads outside the `ForkJoinPool` instance in the runtime executing concurrently. I have a clue that it has something to do with Thread Affinity. Can anyone share some ideas/links?

P.S. Of course, I meant the case when number of threads is no greater than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`

Comment: open your task manager and check how many threads are running; you are underestimating how many threads your processor can handle

Comment: I'm not talking about concurrently running threads. The question is about separate threads running in parallel by separate cores in ForkJoinPool.

Comment: Are you asking how it's possible to properly optimize a thread pool without knowledge of the other threads and pools using the same processors? I've wondered about that.

Comment: when you have 10 cores but 1000 threads, then obviously not all can run parallel, this is not a problem inherent to `ForkJoinPool`; to my knowledge there isn't a garanty for true parallelism as the operating system handles this anyways

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> how is that achieved that each thread in `ForkJoinPool` is certainly run by separate processor/core to provide real parallelism

There is no way within plain Java code to make certain cores run certain threads at certain times. A Java programmer has no direct control over parallelism.

When a Java thread is scheduled for execution on a CPU core, and for how long that execution runs, is up to the host OS thread technology being leveraged by your Java implementation.

As for [*processor affinity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity), also known as *CPU pinning*, see [*How to set a Java thread's cpu core affinity?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13392379/642706). Beware the notice in [Answer by rdalmeida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24187951/642706):

> … thread affinity is pointless unless you have previously isolated the core from kernel/user threads and hardware interrupts